# Очень, невероятно + труднодоступный = свободное словосочетание?

Tags: сложные-прилагательные

[**ПРАВИЛО**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.48)

> При наличии пояснительных (зависимых) слов наречие и прилагательное
> (или причастие) образуют свободное словосочетание: глубокоуважаемый
> автор — глубоко уважаемый читателями автор; густонаселенный район —
> густо населенный рабочими район; легкораненый солдат — легко раненный
> в руку солдат; малоосведомленный читатель — мало осведомленный в этом
> деле читатель; многозначащий взгляд — много значащий для меня взгляд.
> Слитные написания типа малокомпетентный в производстве чугуна инженер,
> экономически слаборазвитые страны являются единичными (встречаются в
> языке газет).

*Некоторые чистейшие озера и реки планеты находятся **в невероятно труднодоступных местах,** чтобы увидеть их, туристам необходимо преодолеть сложный путь.*

*Это озеро находится **в очень труднодоступном горном районе**, на высоте 4 142 метра над уровнем моря.*

**[источник](http://dymontiger.livejournal.com/7405249.html)**

---

Мои страдания:

> Повторюсь, начинали мы в очень труднодоступном горном районе, где на
> тот момент и дорог не было.

"Очень" - это зависимое/пояснительное слово?

Я сейчас не успеваю искать правила, поможите христа ради, сами мы неместные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В качестве варианта:**

Некоторые чистейшие озера и реки планеты находятся **в очень отдаленных или труднодоступных местах**, чтобы увидеть их, туристам необходимо преодолеть сложный путь.

Это озеро находится **в наиболее труднодоступном горном районе**, на высоте 4 142 метра над уровнем моря.

Наречие "очень" плохо сочетается с "труднодоступным" (получается высокая степень труднодоступности), в Нацкорпусе таких примеров нет, встречается  сочетание "самый труднодоступный".

Природа распорядилась так, что алмазы встречаются **в самых труднодоступных** местах. [А. Чертков. Сияние алмазов компании «АЛРОСА» // «Родина», 1999]

Answer (score 1):

Очень - пояснительное слово со значением  степени качества, зависимое было бы "труднодоступный **для туристов** район"

Comment: Значит, "очень труднодоступный" нормально?

Comment: Избыточно, конечно, но ведь употреблено именно в смысле термина, который  автору захотелось усилить. Иногда это возможно, но больше пригодно для газетного стиля. Я бы вообще избегала терминов в таком контексте. Можно было сказать"в почти недоступном", "дальнем".